# Power query on another power query not refreshing data?

Tags: excel, powerquery, excel-2016

I have a power query that pulls data from another workbook when you enter some criteria and hit refresh, pulling it into a table I call `DataTable` - that all works fine.

But I want to make another tab with a power query that offers a summary view - and instead of duplicating all the code again I want to just have it run off the results I've already run. The problem is that it seems to be stuck using whatever data was saved to the workbook rather than whatever I've run.

Like for example this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\servername\path\thisworkbook.xlsm"), null, true),
    Data_Table = Source{[Item="DataTable",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    ...
```

Doesn't actually seem to work even though it's targeting the right table - it only works if I refresh `DataTable` and then literally save the file, and then run the summary query. I want to be able to refresh all of it in the same shot regardless of whether I've saved the file yet or not. Is there a way to force it to update its connection or data?

Comment: Create powerquery  Query1 from other file.  Make powerquery #2 say **Source=Query1** and then the first query will feed the 2nd query

Comment: @horseyride that seemed to work, though I do think it's running that query repeatedly because it's now taking twice as long to run the whole thing rather than just operating on the small set of results it's already generated. There's no way to get it to use the data of the connection that's already executed?

Comment: not sure if you could perhaps end the first query by wrapping it in a Table.Buffer()

Comment: I thought buffering technically stops further changes - isn't that the opposite of what I am trying to get it to read? (i.e. the table after it has run and changed)

Comment: Tried the buffer approach, unfortunately did not work - still suffers from the same problem. I'm honestly shocked there isn't more info about this because I would have assumed it's a common operation!

Comment: more info about this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/multiple-queries

Comment: Yeah the buffer offers a slight speedup but it's still not refreshing correctly until I save the file. I may need to just use PivotTable for this which I was afraid of, can't match the same formatting as the power query.